# Nested queries, promises on nodejs

Tags: node.js

Im trying to build a rest api, fetching a nested mysql queries.

When i fetch the first query, this return a array, then with this array i need to fetch data with another query for each value through a array.map

when the script running, always log a empty array, i think must be cause of promises. any help please?

```
//this the mysql queries
const getTournaments = 'SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "tournament"'
const getTournamentGame = 'SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "tournament_game" AND post_id = ?'

async function fetchType(id){
    return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
        try{
            pool.query(getTournamentGame, [id], (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    return rej(err)
                }else {
                    return res(rows[0].meta_value)
                }
            })
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}


async function mapeado(array) {
    return new Promise (async (resolve,rej) => {
        try{
            var arr = []
            array.map((item) => {
                fetchType(item.ID).then((res) => {
                    var tourData = {
                        id: item.ID,
                        type: res
                    }
                    return tourData
                }).then((data) => {
                   arr.push(data)
                })
            })
            return resolve(arr)

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}

//making rest api
app.get('/tournaments', async (req, res) => {
    pool.query(getTournaments, (err, rows) => {
        mapeado(rows).then(console.log)
    })
})
```

Comment: `array.map` is the cause of your problem. `map` only takes a callback as parameter and doesn't wait for the callback to be done executing. Go with a simple `for (let item of array)` instead.

Comment: Don't mix `async` and Promises. An `async function() { return x }` _already returns a promise_ and is equivalent to a standard `function() { return new Promise(function(resolve) { resolve(x) })}`. The `async` keyword is syntactic sugar that tells the JS engine that the function body should be wrapped in a promise and have that promise returned instead, so either use Promises without `async`, and then you can use `.then` and `.catch`, or use `async` with `await` and try/catch wrapping.